# Express gzip compression issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, compression

I`m writing application with node and express. I want go compress my static files before sending them to the client with [compression](https://github.com/expressjs/compression?_ga=1.209171733.669650275.1486903388) package. Here is my code:

```
var compression = require('compression');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var login = require('./routes/login');
var logout = require('./routes/logout');
var register = require('./routes/register');
var userRoute = require('./routes/user');
var app = express();

//files compression
app.use(compression({ 
  threshold: 0,
  filter: function () { return true; },
  level: 0
}));
```

I tried to use it without options but got the same result. I`m expecting to see Content-Encoding: gzip in response headers, but no luck.

[image]

But with debug I see that compression seem to be take place, is`t it?
[image]

Comment: Level 0 is for "No compression".

Comment: Without options should be fine. Have you tried 'use'ing the compression on sub routes?

Comment: Set -1, then deleted all the options, size have't changed. I have't tried to use it in subroutes.

Answer (score 2):

The level you are using means no compression as per documentation so choose -1 for default or best speed or best compression according to your demands

```
-1 Default compression level (also zlib.Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION).
0 No compression (also zlib.Z_NO_COMPRESSION).
1 Fastest compression (also zlib.Z_BEST_SPEED).
2
3
4
5
6 (currently what zlib.Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION points to).
7
8
9 Best compression (also zlib.Z_BEST_COMPRESSION).
```

Comment: Set -1, no changes.